# Putting things in the same line

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I want to put the following figures in the same line. The code for my work is this:

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \[
        \begin{bmatrix}
        k & 0 \\
        0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
        \]
        \caption{Standard Matrix} 
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{colorforline}{RGB}{49,4,71};

    \draw [very thick, color=colorforline] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node [right]{$x\textsubscript{1}$};
    \draw  [very thick, color=colorforline] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node [above]{$x\textsubscript{2}$};
    \definecolor{recshade}{RGB}{233,226,234};
    \filldraw[very thick, color=colorforline,fill=recshade] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,2.2);
    \draw[colorforline,  very thick] (0,2.2) -- (1.2,2.2) -- (1.2,0) node[below] {} ;%rotation
    \foreach \y in {0,...,9}{
        \draw[colorforline, thick](0,0.\y) -- (1.2,0.\y);
        \draw[colorforline, thick](0,1.\y) -- (1.2,1.\y);
    }
    \draw[colorforline, thick](0,2.0) -- (1.2,2.0);
    \draw[colorforline, thick](0,2.1) -- (1.2,2.1);
    \draw[colorforline, thick](0,2.2) -- (1.2,2.2);

    \filldraw [colorforline] (0,2.2) circle [radius=2pt] node[left] {
        $   \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1
        \end{bmatrix}$
    };
    \coordinate (O) at (3.6,1.4,0);
    \coordinate (1) at (3.6,1,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (1.9,1.4,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1.9,1,0);
    \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (O) to  (A);
    \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (1) to  (B);

    \filldraw [colorforline] (1.2,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[below] {
        $   \begin{bmatrix}
        k \\
        0
        \end{bmatrix}$
    };

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{0$<$k$<$1} 
\end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \definecolor{colorforline}{RGB}{49,4,71};

        \draw [very thick, color=colorforline] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node [right]{$x\textsubscript{1}$};
        \draw  [very thick, color=colorforline] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node [above]{$x\textsubscript{2}$};
        \definecolor{recshade}{RGB}{233,226,234};
        \filldraw[very thick, color=colorforline,fill=recshade] (0,0) rectangle (3,2.2);
        \draw[colorforline,  very thick] (0,2.2) -- (1.2,2.2) -- (3,2.2) node[below] {} ;%rotation
        \foreach \y in {0,...,9}{
            \draw[colorforline, thin](0,0.\y) -- (3,0.\y);
            \draw[colorforline, thin](0,1.\y) -- (3,1.\y);
        }
        \draw[colorforline, thin](0,2.0) -- (3,2.0);
        \draw[colorforline, thin](0,2.1) -- (3,2.1);
        \draw[colorforline, thin](0,2.2) -- (3,2.2);

        \filldraw [colorforline] (0,2.2) circle [radius=2pt] node[left] {
            $   \begin{bmatrix}
            0 \\
            1
            \end{bmatrix}$
        };
        \coordinate (O) at (2.5,1.4,0);
        \coordinate (1) at (0.5,1,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (0.5,1.4,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (2.5,1,0);
        \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (A) to  (O);
        \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (1) to  (B);

        \filldraw [colorforline] (3,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[below] {
            $   \begin{bmatrix}
            k \\
            0
            \end{bmatrix}$
        };

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{k$>$1} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me this result:

[image]

But I want it to be like this:

[image]

Now I notice that the size of the pictures may be large and it would not be able for them to fit in the same line but is there any other way?? like zooming out a bit or dynamically setting the size without going into changing the coordinates which would be a mess for me because I have done a lo.t of work like this already

Comment: Separate `figure` environments won't end up on the same line even if the figures would fit; for that you might try the `subcaption` package. You'll also want to scale the images, which you can do either by passing `[scale=<factor>]` as an optional argument to the `tikzpicture` environment or by putting the whole thing in a `scalebox` (depending on whether you want to scale the text or not).

Comment: @Emma I wish I could understand what you just explained but I am not so familiar with this latex thingy , thanks anyways

Comment: Perhaps I'll add a more complete version below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `minipage` :

You can't use `figure` in `minipage`. You can use `\usepackage{caption}` instead of
I also use `adjustbox` to adjust the image :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \[
      \begin{bmatrix}
        k & 0 \\
        0 & 1
      \end{bmatrix}
    \]
    \captionof{figure}{Std Matrix}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{colorforline}{RGB}{49,4,71};

    \draw [very thick, color=colorforline] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node [right]{$x\textsubscript{1}$};
    \draw  [very thick, color=colorforline] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node [above]{$x\textsubscript{2}$};
    \definecolor{recshade}{RGB}{233,226,234};
    \filldraw[very thick, color=colorforline,fill=recshade] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,2.2);
    \draw[colorforline,  very thick] (0,2.2) -- (1.2,2.2) -- (1.2,0) node[below] {} ;%rotation
    \foreach \y in {0,...,9}{
      \draw[colorforline, thick](0,0.\y) -- (1.2,0.\y);
      \draw[colorforline, thick](0,1.\y) -- (1.2,1.\y);
    }
    \draw[colorforline, thick](0,2.0) -- (1.2,2.0);
    \draw[colorforline, thick](0,2.1) -- (1.2,2.1);
    \draw[colorforline, thick](0,2.2) -- (1.2,2.2);

    \filldraw [colorforline] (0,2.2) circle [radius=2pt] node[left] {
      $   \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1
      \end{bmatrix}$
    };
    \coordinate (O) at (3.6,1.4,0);
    \coordinate (1) at (3.6,1,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (1.9,1.4,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1.9,1,0);
    \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (O) to  (A);
    \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (1) to  (B);

    \filldraw [colorforline] (1.2,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[below] {
      $   \begin{bmatrix}
        k \\
        0
      \end{bmatrix}$
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \captionof{figure}{0$<$k$<$1} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.25\linewidth}
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{colorforline}{RGB}{49,4,71};

    \draw [very thick, color=colorforline] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node [right]{$x\textsubscript{1}$};
    \draw  [very thick, color=colorforline] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node [above]{$x\textsubscript{2}$};
    \definecolor{recshade}{RGB}{233,226,234};
    \filldraw[very thick, color=colorforline,fill=recshade] (0,0) rectangle (3,2.2);
    \draw[colorforline,  very thick] (0,2.2) -- (1.2,2.2) -- (3,2.2) node[below] {} ;%rotation
    \foreach \y in {0,...,9}{
      \draw[colorforline, thin](0,0.\y) -- (3,0.\y);
      \draw[colorforline, thin](0,1.\y) -- (3,1.\y);
    }
    \draw[colorforline, thin](0,2.0) -- (3,2.0);
    \draw[colorforline, thin](0,2.1) -- (3,2.1);
    \draw[colorforline, thin](0,2.2) -- (3,2.2);

    \filldraw [colorforline] (0,2.2) circle [radius=2pt] node[left] {
      $   \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1
      \end{bmatrix}$
    };
    \coordinate (O) at (2.5,1.4,0);
    \coordinate (1) at (0.5,1,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (0.5,1.4,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2.5,1,0);
    \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (A) to  (O);
    \draw[very thick, ->, color=colorforline] (1) to  (B);

    \filldraw [colorforline] (3,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[below] {
      $   \begin{bmatrix}
        k \\
        0
      \end{bmatrix}$
    };

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
  \captionof{figure}{k$>$1}
\end{minipage}
  \captionof{figure}{The whole caption}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not bad sir, could you please help me with one more thing. If I want to give this whole line of figures (using your code) a single caption, can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps it'd look better if the two graphs were bottom-aligned :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really do want three separate figures on the same line, flav's answer is very nice. If you actually want the three images as a single figure with one number and caption, try the [`subcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en) package. If you don't want individual captions at all, you can also just put all three pictures in the same figure.

I also mentioned in my comment above that there are several ways to scale the pictures, depending on your intent. You can either a) add a scaling factor to the `tikzpicture` environment itself or b) scale the picture after it is rendered. The first method will leave some elements un-scaled, such as text and line width, while the second scales everything.

I've illustrated these different approaches below (with simpler dummy pictures for brevity).

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz,changes,amsmath,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \[
    \begin{bmatrix}
    k & 0 \\
    0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \]
    \caption{Standard Matrix}
    \label{subfig:matrix}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
      \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle node {$0<k<1$} (5,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$0<k<1$}
    \label{subfig:smallk}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
      \draw (0,0) node[above right] {Text} rectangle (5,5) node[below left] {$x\geq 3$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$k>1$}
    \label{subfig:largek}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Three figures arranged using \texttt{subcaption} with scaling directly on the \texttt{tikzpicture} environments.}
  \label{fig:first}
\end{figure}
Using \texttt{subcaption}, you can refer to subfigures \ref{subfig:matrix}, \ref{subfig:smallk}, \ref{subfig:largek}, or figure \ref{fig:first}. You can even refer to subfigure \subref{subfig:matrix} of figure \ref{fig:first}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  $\displaystyle % This gets the styling of math display mode without the line breaks.
  \begin{bmatrix}
  k & 0 \\
  0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
  $
  \hfill
  \scalebox{.5}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle node {$0<k<1$} (5,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \hfill
  \scalebox{.5}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[above right] {Text} rectangle (5,5) node[below left] {$x\geq 3$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{The same three figures with no subcaption, scaled using \texttt{scalebox}.}
  \label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

Without \texttt{subcaption}, you can only refer to figure \ref{fig:second}.

\end{document}
```

(Note that the `[b]` argument to `subfigure` indicates that the figures should be bottom-aligned.)

Comment: pardon for the delayed comment. thank you ma'am. appreciated

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I get [b].3 in the actual pdf output. Why?